# Можно ли слово "возможно" употреблять в значении "можно"?

Tags: выбор-слов, значение-слов

Может, когда-то это не возбранялось?

> Зато мне, например, возможно забыть фамилию автора… Остаточное явление
>   доморощенного скорочтения – я запоминаю лишь первую букву.

Или здесь в значении *я могу*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Ушакова есть значение

> 1. Такой, что может или мог случиться, произойти.

Видимо, это отголосок этого значения: *со мной это может случиться*.

Я бы не правила, стиль у автора своеобразный.